# TextWatcher not working in DialogFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-dialogfragment, textwatcher

I use `TextInputLayout` from this library:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

I have following part in the layout:

```
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/phoneNumberLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:errorEnabled="true">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/label_phone_number"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I have Kotlin Android Extensions is enabled and I  try to assign TextWatcher to `phoneNumber` as follows:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    phoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            Log.e("DialogFragment", "phoneNumber::onTextChanged()")
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            Log.e("DialogFragment", "phoneNumber current text: " + s)
        }
    })
}
```

Nothing happens when I start typing , hours wasted... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The snippet provided looks alright. Check you are attaching to the right view. Might be you have multiple views with the same id in the layout?

Comment: `onActivityCreated` seems to be wrong place to do this. Try `onViewCreated` where your layout is inflated and assigned to a fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the textwatcher in `onActivityCreated` which does not hold your root View. You should reference your phone(TextInputEditText) from `View` inflated in `onCreateView` or inside `onViewCreated` as suggested by @Miha_x64. Your code is correct though but the problem is with the view reference.